# How to add multiple attribute values to xml file in JAVA using DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, xslt, xml-parsing

I have One XML Like

```
<root>
<name id="1">Abc</name>
<salary>25000</salary>
</root>
```

I want something like this

```
<root>
<name id="1,2">Abc</name>
<salary>25000</salary>
</root>
```

I am able to create the attribute by using DOM parser as:

```
Document doc = _docBuilder.newDocument();`
Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
attr.setValue("1");
name.setAttributeNode(attr);
```

How can I get multiple attribute values for the same attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML [does not support attributes with multiple values](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp).

You could certainly do: `attr.setValue("1,2");`

However that really isn't very XML friendly.  Also, you probably shouldn't have more than one value for an id.  You may wish to consider something like this:

```
<thing>
  <name>Abc</name>
  <reference_ids>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
  </reference_ids>
</thing>
```